# Cannot get trial license to load for itext 7

Tags: itext7

I am trying to explore the pdfsweep functionality of itext 7.  I have obtained a 30 day trial license.  When I call `LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(path-to-key-file)`, it returns without any errors, but when I attempt to instantiate a `PdfCleanUpTool`, I get the following error:

```
LicenseKeyException License file not loaded.  com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey.checkLicense (LicenseKey.java:410)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's the kind of support questions you'd better ask iText directly. That's what the 30 day trial is for. Now we have the difficulty in finding out which prospect you are, because "user12345" isn't really identifiable. Mail your question directly to the email address where you got the license key from, and we'll know who you are and what's inside your key.

Comment: I felt a little odd about posting it here, but multiple places made it sound like the right thing to do, including the email in which I received the license link and the support page on the itext website.

`Questions? Ask the community on Stackoverflow, there are lots of iText examples and we continue to add more all the time.`
`Where to post what type of question
    How do I... ? - StackOverflow's iText or iTextSharp topics.
    I got this error, why? - StackOverflow's iText or iTextSharp topics.`

Comment: And this, friends, is why closed-source software gets such a bad rap. Keep customer supporting gud guys!

Comment: If you think it feels odd, then it probably is. :) We're already on it.

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this. It's a question about the functioning of a particular tool. Can we not ask questions about Apache Commons either?

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close either. In fact, I just upvoted the question. Is StackOverflow the best possible place for user12345 to get the fastest possible answer for this particular question? No it isn't. Is this question relevant for StackOverflow? Yes it is. Will an answer be posted once a solution has been found? Absolutely. Anyway, let's move that discussion to meta.stackoverflow.com, shall we? See also this answer on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974/280459

Comment: This is a question about a specific licensing issue at a specific vendor or project, and the issue can't be dealt with by users here at SO. Vendor account specific questions (where it's necessary to identify the specific user or account) need to be addressed to the vendor support via email or their web site. Use of iText programmatically is on-topic here; individual account support questions are not, and neither are questions regarding licensing.

Comment: It is not a question about licenses. It is a question about an error encountered while using the product. It is possible that it must be resolved by the vendor. It is also possible that it must be resolved programmatically. Either way, once the solution is found, it would be nice if there were somewhere on the internet where people with a similar problem would be able to see how it was resolved. What a magical world it would be if this were possible. If only....

Comment: The root cause has been found, one of the iText developers will post an answer soon. Thank you for reporting this issue. To @KenWhite: it was determined that it was *not* an individual account support question. It was something that we commonly refer to as a "bug". As stated in the link I posted above, StackOverflow recommends that bug reports go directly to the vendor. However with any API library it's always very hard to determine the difference between a user bug and a vendor bug, so it's reasonable to ask on StackOverflow. Further discussion on Meta, maybe?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: But when this was posted that bug was not yet known, so at that point it was still an individual account issue. And this [has been discussed in Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576).

Comment: That is what I have been saying all along, Ken. Perhaps you missed my initial comment? I invite you to scroll up. This particular case is a borderline case between an account issue and an API question. I believe that the OP came to SO to ask the question in good faith.

Comment: I swear... The only thing that matters to this community is the sensibilities of megalomaniacs. The question is about an unanticipated exception in the code. AND it turns out, regardless of what @KenWhite *thought* the problem was, the problem was *always* in the code. It's not, and never was, an issue of a particular user's license. It affects ALL users. And anybody with a similar problem would benefit from this post. Nobody would bat an eye if this was an open-source project that required a license agreement.

Comment: @TimPote: So fine. You disagree. Point made. Name calling and insults are hardly necessary, and I'd think someone of your experience and rep here would know that already. There's no reason to get personal or rude just because someone disagrees with your point of view. And if someone asks a question here about the legalities of an open-source license agreement, it would be off-topic (but appropriate for [programmers.se]).

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: I certainly didn't say or imply anything about it not being asked in good faith.

Comment: Just FYI, PDFSweep may be closed source, but the main iText Core product *is* Open Source and uses exactly the same license key mechanism to differentiate between an AGPL user and a commercial user. "Nobody would bat an eye if this was an open-source project that required a license agreement." - guess what. :) and tomorrow I'm off to the beach for a couple of days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key you received was a license key for iText 7 Core and not for the add-ons. This was due to a bug on our end. I've fixed this and if you request a new key, you should be able to use your license key.